# Wordpress custom field can't handle single quotes

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

I'm creating a custom post which has several custom fields. When the value entered for the custom fields contains a single quote, everything after it is chopped off. Is there a filter I can use to escape quotes so they are read in as part of the string?

I have a lot of custom fields, but here as an example of the code I'm using.

```
// prefix of meta keys, optional
// use underscore (_) at the beginning to make keys hidden, for example $prefix =     '_rw_';
// you also can make prefix empty to disable it
$prefix = 'rw_';
$meta_boxes = array();
// first meta box
$meta_boxes[] = array(
'id' => 'entry_data',                           // meta box     id, unique per meta box
'title' => 'Entry Data',            // meta box title
'pages' => array('dictionary_entry'),   // post types, accept custom post types as     well, default is array('post'); optional
'context' => 'normal',                      // where the meta box appear: normal (default), advanced, side; optional
'priority' => 'high',                       // order of meta box: high (default), low; optional
'fields' => array(                          // list of meta fields
    array(
        'name' => 'Definition 1',                   // field name
        'desc' => 'What does this mean?',   // field description, optional
        'id' => $prefix . 'definition1',                // field id, i.e. the meta key
        'type' => 'text',                       // text box
        'std' => '',                    // default value, optional
        'validate_func' => 'check_name'         // validate function, created below, inside RW_Meta_Box_Validate class
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'Example 1',                  // field name
        'desc' => 'Use it in a sentence?',  // field description, optional
        'id' => $prefix . 'example1',               // field id, i.e. the meta key
        'type' => 'text',                       // text box
        'std' => '',                    // default value, optional
        'validate_func' => 'check_name'         // validate function, created below, inside RW_Meta_Box_Validate class
    ),
)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using [`htmlentities($value, ENT_QUOTES)`](http://pl2.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) on value read from the textbox?

Comment: That's the kind of thing I'd like to do, but I'm not sure where to do it. I need that function to apply to the entered text (as it's saved) because the single quotes are clipping off the rest of the string.

Comment: so you probably want to use `htmlentities` in `'validate_func'` ora ny other place where you read the text box value and want to do sth with it.

Comment: This fixed the issue for me.  Run it on the field data before saving it during the `save_post` hook and it'll come back up as it should every time.